# Why was Katniss Everdeen wearing her arena outfit in this scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-hunger-games

During the first *Hunger Games*, Katniss hallucinates under the influence of tracker-jacker venom/stings.

She recalls her father's death and then there is a scene with her mother.

I'm curious why Katniss Everdeen was wearing her games/arena outfit in the scene with her mother.

Comment: Some context here would be useful. Which movie are we talking about and which scene?

Comment: The first movie and the scene where it shows her father in the explosion

Comment: Perhaps you can find an image to share?

Comment: I do not know how to share image but there is a video on youtube i know. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YAw4CZn44_c If that is helpful to you

Comment: The Hallucination scene

Comment: Hey @J.Kirby, I'm upvoting your question because of the state it is now in, congrats on getting back to an even footing, with any luck you'll get a few more upvotes to earn you some rep! Whilst you wait to find out be sure to check the differences between the question you first posted (which I would have voted to close in the state it was in) and what it is now that Paulie_D and Napoleon Wilson have helped out. You can see the history by clicking the 'edited X hours go' link or going here: https://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/96186/revisions .Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 4):

### Because it's a hallucination not an *actual* memory.

Obviously, the audience needs to understand that she's not *really*  talking to her mother here...she's still affected by the tracker-jacker venom and leaving her in her arena outfit helps us understand that.